# How to show same progress bar for loading data from internet and displaying content on UI

Tags: android

I am creating an app in which I have to fetch some data from Internet and show it to user on UI.
I have create an progress bar in `AsyncTask` `onPreExecute()` method and in `onPostExecute()` method I have passed all data to another Activity and startActivty. Then I dismiss the progress dialog. But, it not  fine.
As when the second `activity` loaded data on UI in `onCreate` method then ProgressBar hangs.
How do I solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        proDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        proDialog.setTitle("Support Manager");
        proDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        proDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        proDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        proDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected RepresentativeData doInBackground(String... params) {
        JSONObject result = null;

        try {
            result = client.reprentativeDetailNode(params[0]);
            LoginJsonParsing loginJsonParsing = new LoginJsonParsing();
            Details = loginJsonParsing
                    .Details(result);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Details;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Data result) {

        Intent secActivity = new Intent(mContext,YourRepresentative.class);
        secAcitivity.putExtra("detail", result);

        mContext.startActivity(secActivity);
        proDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code rather then decp

Comment: try  proDialog.dismiss(); before mContext.startActivity(secActivity);

Comment: I have also used proDialog.dismiss() before mContext.startActivity(secActivity).But if I do this then progress dialog is dismissed but secActivity takes 2-3 sec to load.As I have loads all the data in onCreate() method of secActivity after retrieving it here in AsyncTask class.

Comment: you can can do that as you are passing on activity content to progress bar and closing it from another content so you need to pass getapplicationContent() rather mContext and close progress bar in second activity when thing done

Comment: 03-06 20:21:30.225: E/AndroidRuntime(10997): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: when I used the getApplicationContext() instead of Activity context above error comes to me.

Comment: have you initialised progress bar  new ProgressDialog(mContext) this way?

Comment: Now I have been initializing it like:new ProgressDialog(mContext.getApplicationContext).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a progress to be displayed when switching to a new activity

Comment: That's ok but my UI taking more time to load.So I want to show dialog while switching to an new Activity.

Comment: do loading task in background and show progress bar and close when done